# bash expansion with linux command

Tags: linux, bash

I want to pass info to the command using positional parameters within my script but it's not working.  Is it possible with parameter expansion?

```
lvresize -r -L 4G /dev/mapper/vol-opt

lvresize -r -L "$($2)G" "$opt"
```

(The value of `$2` is `4`)

Answer (score 4):

If your second positional parameter is `4` you would want to pass it like so:

```
lvresize -r -L "$2G" "$opt"
```

However I would recommend using braces just for cleanliness

```
lvresize -r -L "${2}G" "$opt"
```

It is unclear how `opt` is being set but I will assume you have that taken care of.

---

When you write `$($2)` you are performing [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) so it's trying to execute the command named `4` which likely doesn't exist.

---

The braces would normally be **required** for other types of parameters in this situation as they will prevent any trailing adjacent text from being considered part of the variable name.

For example:

```
$ var=good
$ varg=bad
$ echo "$varg"
bad
$ echo "${var}g"
goodg
```

Comment: Right. Only the positional parameters are allowed to *start* with a digit, and positional parameters may *only* contain digits. The shell has no trouble separating `$2` from `"G"`. Us humans however may need a little more help.

Comment: [user@linux ~]# lvresize -r -L "${4}G" "$opt"
  Size requires number argument.
  Invalid argument for --size: G
  Error during parsing of command line.

Comment: @user63858: Change the `${4}` to `${2}` unless you are now passing your size as the fourth parameter.  Also it looks like you are doing that from your command line and not from within a script.  Are you being clear about your intent here?

Comment: The script will run as below:

./scriptname $1 $2 $3 $4

$1=var
$2=opt
$3=home
$4=tmp

so default arguments value will be passed to the command so it can resize.

Comment: @user63858: I think you don't understand positional parameters.

Comment: It's okay to assume as its www so no comment on that but the issue is that command is not taking it and throwing an error.  I have run the command as you wrote and provided output.  Let me know if anything else is needed.  I started with it on the stack first but got no traction and thought this is a dedicated forum for that.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54678879/case-statement-in-bash-function-not-working

Comment: @user63858: You are not passing your arguments correctly.  It should be something like: `./scriptname something 4 something_else etc`

Comment: passing it as ./scriptname 3 4 2 1 if that makes it clear.  Thanks

Comment: @user63858: It doesn't because earlier you said something else.

Comment: I understand your example.  I will play with it more to see what's missing on my side as its working in your example.